# Is AES128 or AES256 on Android?

Tags: java, android, encryption

Greetings,

On Android, we can't specify AES128 or AES256. But is AES128, or AES256 actually run when using "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"?

I tried something like below

```
SecretKeyFactory sf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC");
KeySpec ks = new PBEKeySpec(masterPassword.toCharArray(),k1,1320,256);
secKey = sf.generateSecret(ks);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey, generateIV(cipher));
```

The SecretKeyFactory created has a keySize of 256, and the  keyLength specified in PBEKeySpec seems doesn't matter. No matter 256 or 128, or any other positive number, the secKey generated always has 256 keySize. Since we passed the secKey to initialize the cipher, so now, does the encryption will be run using AES128, or AES256?

Thanks!

Comment: Bill Can you test by encrypting with a 256 bit key and try to decrypt with the first 128 bits of the same key and let us know what happens so that we do not need to repeat the test :) PS. I am just passing a 256 bit key from a multi-hashed (seed+password).

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html) should allow you to determine the strengths and ciphers you have available in the runtime image.  I don't know if it will kick you out at this point but by specifying PBEKeySpec with a length of 256 I think you might have it.

Comment: In my testing, when generate the key using SecretKeyFactory sf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC"); then the secKey's keySize will be 256. If SecretKeyFactory sf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC");, then the keySize will be 128.

Comment: Sorry - just noticed the EXPLICIT PBEWITHSHAAND***256BIT***AES-CBC-BC designator in there.

Answer (score 0):

> On Android, we can't specify AES128 or
>   AES256. But is AES128, or AES256
>   actually run when using
>   "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"?

Am I wrong suggesting that none is actually determined at getInstance()? I suppose the length of the cipher's key will be determined only after call to init() where you set a key which is of certain length.

Comment: Both cases (keySize 128/256) works on Android. But I don't know if the keySize determined AES128/AES256 run. Or only AES128 actually run in both cases?

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you. AES block size remains the same. And AES key size is determined only after call to `init()`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard